# UNRAR in javascript

Tags: javascript, unrar

is there a library to **unRAR** files?  The rar files I have to work with contain multiple files.

I'm looking for a way to navigate rar content, and get a blob with the uncompressed content of a selected file within the .rar one.

I'm already using [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) to unzip files, and need the same for RAR.  Thanks a lot for your time reading it.

Comment: First link when you google `unrar javascript`: [unrar.js](http://code.google.com/p/bitjs/source/browse/unrar.js?r=cb17511a054f486de5b8272ffa78ee0510d7cc5b)

Comment: I can see you didn't try it.  I couldn't make it work, neither find an alternative.

Comment: @YoArgentino did you try to run the script into a web worker?

Comment: Yes, but the code is undocumented and need a lot of energy to run it. And reading it, I found it supports so few rar versions, and I need more versions supported for my application.

Comment: The new home for bitjs is at GitHub for about a decade: https://github.com/codedread/bitjs - but it does not support every version of RAR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But bitjs is no longer maintained, and very hard to use.

Try https://github.com/workhorsy/uncompress.js . It even works with RAR 5.

Here is the most trivial example I could make: http://workhorsy.github.io/uncompress.js/examples/trivial/index.html .